# ConnectApi.NotFoundException: Resource not found

Tags: apex, chatter, chatter-feed, connect-api

I am getting an error when using the `ConnectApi` to post a feed:

**ConnectApi.NotFoundException: Resource not found.
Class.ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.getFeedElement: line 1502, column Class.ChatterPostParser: line 154, column 1 Class.RestComments.insertComment: line 66, column 1**

I am trying this code:

```
List<User> mentionUsers = new List<User>();
ConnectApi.CommentInput feedCommentInput = 

ChatterPostParser.parseChatterCommentWithMentions(comment, mentionUsers);
ConnectApi.Comment commentRep = ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.postCommentToFeedElement(
                                  Network.getNetworkId(),
                                  (Id)feedId,
                                  feedCommentInput,
                                  null);
```

Comment: Can you please provide the code from which you are calling this code. I mean are you calling this code by a web-service ?

Comment: @TarachandKarwal I am calling this from REST API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are calling it from Rest Api then **Network.getNetworkId()** will not work and you have to hard code the network Id. So place network Id instead of **Network.getNetworkId()** and it will work definitely.

Comment: Thanks it worked after hard coding the id, any workaround to make it dynamic?

Comment: Create a Custom Setting and store Id in it. So it's value will be org wise not will be static always.